# Does cancer really remain undetected about 80% of its life?

Tags: human-biology, cancer

I was reading *Atomic Habits* by James Clear, who mentioned this and decided to google it. The only mention of this at least in the first search page was from [this source from February, 2012](https://angio.org/cancer-may-grow-undetected-for-a-decade-or-more/). Is there any new resource that mentions this that isn't a decade old?

> A study conducted by researchers at Stanford University School of Medicine provides strong new evidence that malignant tumors may grow undetected in the body for a decade or more before they can be sniffed out by the most sophisticated blood tests currently available.

Comment: There is undetected and there is unidentified; I detected my cancer symptoms for about a year before I found a doctor that could identify it as cancer.

Comment: I'd suggest finding that Stanford study on PubMed or google scholar and looking for studies that cite it.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - The question is, I believe, about size, not symptoms.

Comment: Your source bases "undected" on a *blood test* indicating the presence of a cancerous lesion. This says more about the lack of tumor-specific biomarkers than anything else. Many cancers present with symptoms. If you want to know about advances in tumor-specific biomarkers in the past decade, I'd look for that.

Comment: The size was stage 4 , the largest size category, I understand.

Comment: Once the Dr decided to do a blood test , it required only a couple days to identify it as HPV 16 induced cancer.